# Can anyone explain line by line how this simple 'binary representation of a number with recursion' program runs?

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures

Here's the code. Explain the recursion part please. Shouldn't it print only 0?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void bin(unsigned n)
{

    if (n > 1)
        bin(n/2);


    printf("%d ", n % 2);
}

void main(void)
{
    bin(7);
    printf("\n");
    bin(4);
}
```

Comment: Execute this code yourself, by hand.  Write down on paper what happens at each step, including the call stack.  You should experience a revelation.  (If you don't already know how to do this, you need more help than we can give you.)

Answer (score 3):

Below, different indentation level represents different level in recursion.

```
bin (7)
n is greater than 1, so calls bin(7/2), i.e. bin(3)

    bin(3)
    n is greater than 1, so calls bin(3/2), i.e. bin(1)

            bin(1)
            n is NOT greater than 1, so bin(1/2) is NOT called, i.e. last step of recursion 
            prints (1 % 2) => prints 1
            bin(1) returns

    prints (3 % 2) => prints 1
    bin(3)returns

prints (7 % 2) => prints 1
bin(7) returns
```

So, 1 1 1 is printed in screen.

---

You can try to make a similar flow for `bin(4)`. Also try for `bin(2)`, `bin(1)`, and `bin(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't it print only 0?

Well, you need to understand how recursion works. 
You can read about recursion [here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/recursion.html)

Here is a brief overview. When you call bin(n/2) in your function, it saves the current function call on a stack. It keeps on saving the function calls on the stack until the base case is encountered. Once the base case encountered, the stack begins to "unwind". So, all the previous function calls that are saved on the stack are called. 
Therefore, it prints more than just zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
bin(7)
    if(7>1)// Condition is True
        {
            bin(7/2) // == bin(3) 1st recursion
                {
                    if(3>1) // Condition is True
                    {
                        bin(3/2) // == bin(1) 2nd recursion
                        {
                            if(1>1) //False
                                   // Now printf function executes in a reverse way bin function called 
                                printf("%d\n",1%2);// Ans 1 

                        }
                        printf("%d\n",3%2); Ans 1
                    }
                }
            printf("%d\n",7%2); // Ans 1
        }
```

In your code whenever if condition becomes true it calls bin() recursively. And note here n/2 and n%2  o/p is not assigned to n (i.e. its not equivalent to n=n/2 and n=n%2), so value of n remain same for respective recursive function. (i.e. bin(7) called then 7/2 and 7%2 occur.)